# Array of selectors: for loop vs. $.each

Tags: jquery

Given the following array of selectors (each of which are `display: none` in the our css) and for loop:

```
var arr = ['#home', '#news', '#tidy'];

for (i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
    $(arr[i]).toggle();
}
```

What is an equivalent using $.each ( and presumably $(this) )?

**Edit**

OK I understand using join:

```
var s = arr.join();
$(s).toggle();
```

I did not realize that "toggle like many other jQuery methods calls each method internally so there is no need to use each" so +1 to you @undefined, however...

The question was original put forth because even when I:

```
$.each(arr, function(){
    $(this).text("my id is " + this + ".");
});
```

I get undefined (!) errors. (OK to be fair there was .toggle and .insertAfter etc., I'm attempting to simplify) Why is the above not equivalent to:

```
$('#home').text('my id is #home.');
$('#news').text('my id is #news.');
$('#tidy').text('my id is #tidy.');
```

?

**Edit 2**

OK it was a syntax issue - `$(this)` requires a prepending `'' +`:

```
$('' + this).text('My id is ' + this + '.')
```

Is there a rule as to when `$(this)` requires such treatment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
var arr = ['#home', '#news', '#tidy'];
$(arr.join(',')).toggle();
```

$(arr.join(',')) => $('#home, #news, #tidy'), which selects all 3 elements then toggle() operates on all the selected elements.

---

If you do

```
$.each(arr, function(){
    $(this).text("my id is " + this + ".");
});
```

the `this` is actually a string object not a string primitive so what you get in return form `$(this)` is a jQuery object wrapping a string object not the element that the selector will match. Adding a string primitive `''` to a string object gives you a string primitive which is why it works that way.
If you have to use `$.each` better to use the arguments passed to the callback function, the first argument is the index of the array and the second is the value at the index.

```
$.each(arr, function(index, value){
    $(value).text("my id is " + this + ".");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2TPLD/

Comment: we don't need to put `,` in join . The default separator is comma `(,)` .. just put `$(arr.join()).toggle();`

Comment: @rab I forgot about that. But I rather the explicit `,`

Comment: Terrific explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use Array object's `join` method:

```
$(arr.join()).toggle(); // => $('#home, #news, #tidy').toggle();
```

`toggle` like many other jQuery methods calls `each` method internally so there is no need to use `each`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

You can use Array join method:

```
  var arr = ['home', 'news', 'tidy'];

for (i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
    $('#'+arr[i]).toggle();
}
```

or

```
$.each(arr, function() {
 $("#" + this).toggle();
});
```

or

```
 var arr = ['#home', '#news', '#tidy'];
 $(arr.join(',')).toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach loop as follows

```
var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];
jQuery.each(arr, function() {
    $("#" + this).text("My id is " + this + ".");

});
```

Or in your case

```
var arr = ['#home', '#news', '#tidy'];
  jQuery.each(arr, function() {
    $(this).text("My id is " + this + ".");

});
```